# What rules exist for the druids wild form ability in terms of beasts you have "seen"?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape

This is regards to Dnd 5e.
Do you actually have to see a living creature? Can you see a picture in a book or a script? What if you only see a part of a beast such as only the right hand/claw/etc is visible? What if you see a statue of a creature?

Comment: Are you looking for ways to implement this at your table, or for a definitive answer in the rulebook?

Comment: also related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/109351/27377

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the rule as intended is that you are familiar with the creature. I don't see any rules in the PHB about gaining additional shapes, so it comes down to the DM. (opinion)*I would probably be okay with drawings with a nature check of some kind?* Again, lots of ways to handle it.

Beside the standard "up to the dm" answer, let me link you an [Unearthed Arcana PDF](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_Druid11272016_CAWS.pdf). On the last few pages, it provides more of a framework for those who want more concrete rules (Keep in mind this is playtest material). They suggest:

> **Observation**. You learn the beast's shape after observing its behavior for at least 1 hour and succeeding on an Intelligence (Nature) check with a DC equal to 10 + the beast's challenge rating. For this observation period, your vantage point-whether physical or magical-must be within 150 feet of the beast. If you previously spent at least 1 hour reading a scholarly work about the creature, you have advantage on the check.
>
> **Interaction**. You learn the beast's shape after interacting with it peacefully for 10 minutes and succeeding on a Wisdom (Animal Handling) check with a DC equal to 10 + the beast's challenge rating. For this interaction period, you must be within 15 feet of the beast, and if you spend at least a minute petting it, you have advantage on the check.

I am currently play testing that (as the DM) and love it.

Comment asks me to elaborate on my (opinion) above and the fact that I am using the UA.

Before the UA came out, we ran a homebrew game. A druid player was a bit upset that most of our campaign was urban / ghost hunting. They also felt uncomfortable asking to take the story from the group so they could watch bugs. Of course, I encouraged them to take the reigns, but also offered them the ability to study writings/drawings of the creature. Based on the level of knowledge they had, I'd set a DC (usually 15 or so) for a nature check). The role determined if he gained that beast shape or not. I admit this is a bit more "wizard"-y than a druid, but you could possibly consider combining the systems... give advantage on the check if they have a decent understanding of the creature.

At any rate, I would go with the UA article at this point. If the player wants to be some sort of nature documenter or something, I may tweak the system to make sure they have fun.

Comment: I'm curious about your comment that you are testing this as a DM and love it, in contrast with "(opinion)I would probably be okay with drawings with a nature check of some kind". The proposed rules seem _quite_ restrictive, especially for Moon druids and higher-level forms, while "find a picture in a library and study it" is almost the opposite. Can you elaborate?

Comment: So, for whatever it's worth, the *Xanathar's Guide* section uses some of the introductory text from the UA article, but turns out *not* to be restrictive. Instead, it is tables of beasts by CR broken out by terrain (Arctic, Coast, etc.), and offered simply as suggestions.