# Do attacks that deal damage multiple times count as multiple damage events for death saving throws?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw

Note: I don't play D&D, but reading some of the Hot Network Questions about saving throws (particularly [Does Evasion allow half damage even when unconscious?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/121744/does-evasion-allow-half-damage-even-when-unconscious)) has made me curious.

According to the rules on death saving throws, taking damage means failing a death saving throw. Suppose I cast Magic Missile using a 1st level Spell Slot at a creature or PC with 0 HP, but which hasn't failed any death saving throws yet. Since all 3 darts hit, does this mean the creature or PC fails 3 death saving throws? My interpretation of the rules leads me to believe yes, but I'm not fully sure.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey I'm not sure the dupe is good. It essentially says "Whenever an attack is made it counts as 1 source of damage", but Magic Missile doesn't make an attack (no attack roll), so the question of whether that is 1 or 3 failed death saving throws remains unanswered.

Comment: @nwp I don't think it matters if an attack roll is needed or not, the linked post seems fairly clear to me that each hit is a 'source of damage' and is resolved separately.

Comment: @nwp How about this duplicate: [Would striking someone at 0 hit points with an entire Magic Missile spell automatically kill them?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73190/would-striking-someone-at-0-hit-points-with-an-entire-magic-missile-spell-automa)