# Can a druid Wild Shape into Sangzor from the Curse of Strahd adventure?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, druid, wild-shape, curse-of-strahd

During the module *Curse of Strahd*, I can encounter the evil Giant Goat [Sangzor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/sangzor) (p. 160). The goat has special properties: higher CR, resistance to nonmagical weapons & more hit points.

Can I Wild Shape into Sangzor?

Comment: Related :https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109342/can-a-druid-shapechange-into-the-form-of-a-specific-individual-beast

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. Sangzor has its own statblock, this isn't just some academic question about appearance or fulfilling the "beast you have seen" requirement.

Comment: @Miniman I modified the question to focus only on this particular monster then and removed references to the general question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes, if you are a level 8+ druid (or level 2+ Moon Druid)

The rules on wildshape state:

> [...]you can use your action to magically assume the shape of a beast **that you have seen before**.

There is also the table of CR limitations:

\begin{array}{r|lll}
\text{Level} & \text{Max CR} & \text{Limitations} & \text{Example} \\
\hline
2nd & ¼ & \text{No Flying or Swimming} & Wolf  \\
4th & ½ & No Flying & Crocodile \\
\text{*8th} & 1 &   & \text{Giant Eagle}
\end{array}

This table shows that you must be a level 8+ druid to change into a monster of CR1.

*Unless you are a Moon Druid, which can choose a CR 1 creature as early as level 2:

> Starting at 2nd level, you can use your Wild Shape to transform into a beast with a challenge rating as high as 1

---

In the Curse of Strahd Campaign book, Sangzor is described as follows:

> Sangzor is a **giant goat** known for its supernatural
>   resilience and evil disposition. [...] Modify its statistics as follows:
>
> - It has an Intelligence of 6 (-2 modifier) and is chaotic evil.
> - It has 33 hit points.
> - It has resistance to bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing damage from nonmagical attacks.
> - **Its challenge rating is 1**

So the campaign says Sangzor is a [Giant Goat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-goat) (MM p. 326) with the modified stats above. A giant Goat is a CR½ *beast* which means you're good on the CR and creature type as well.

Therefore, if you have encountered Sangzor, you have (presumably*) seen him and if your druid is at least level 8 (or is level 2+ and Circle of the Moon), it clears the CR limitation.

<sub>The campaign, as written, states "The mist and snowfall prevent seeing anything more than 60 feet away." So if your party was a little spread out and the goat was defeated while the druid was more than 60' away from the action, it is possible for the party to defeat Sangzor without the druid seeing it to add to its repertoire of forms</sub>

Comment: @mini Oh, yeah. Duh. Thanks!

Comment: Silly question, but is sangzor a beast per his stat block?

Comment: @Naut "Giant Goat" is a beast. I'll add that info to the answer.

Comment: Is that the full stat block? Figured a giant goat was a beast, but didn't know if it actually said *beast* like the MM has in the block for creature types.

Comment: @naut MM says "Large beast, unaligned" for Giant Goat and the CoS campaign says Sangzor is a Giant Goat (but with explicit changes to the Giant Goat stats). Is that the clarification you needed? Can I change the answer in some way to make it clearer?

Comment: Guess not, I've never played a published module so didnt know they'd present stat blocks like.a bullet list. If that's the case, then yeah...giant goat and this is fine :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92171/discussion-between-rykara-and-nautarch).

Comment: I was about to post an answer arguing that Sangzor can't be a beast because beasts cannot have non-magical attack resistance.  In the process, I noticed that the Sangzor statblock is listed as a Beast on dndbeyond.com.  So nevermind, I guess.

Comment: @pink that's odd that dnd beyond treats Sangzor as a separate creature but the campaign book does not provide a separate creature stat block. Is that just a convenience thing for digitally inclined people?

Comment: @Rykara dnd beyond does that for a lot of other creatures, such as the Ice Spider from SKT (p.127), the Giant Rocktopus from OotA (p. 28), or the Four-armed Gargoyle from TftYP (p. 129).

Comment: @Rykara: What Merudo said. The DDB staff have hinted that it has something to do with the encounter builder that they are currently working on (besides it also being convenient for users otherwise). Variants of existing statblocks that have modifications made to them in official adventures (or in "variant" sidebars in the monster books) do have separate statblock listings on DDB.